# Subclass fstream and decrypt data on-the-fly

Tags: c++

I open an `fstream` for reading a protobuf file.

```
std::fstream input(pbpath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

Now I want to be able to encrypt this file (beforehand) and decrypt the data on the fly while reading from my specialized `fstream` subclass, so it appears to the reader that it comes from an unecrypted file.

What methods do I have to override to decrypt on the fly?

Comment: So why mess with `fstream`? read a chunk of bytes from ifstream, do something with them and write them to ofstream. don't see why derive from the standard class

Comment: But I need an `(i)fstream` as input for protobuf? Also I only want to decrypt incremental on a read call, not manually.

Answer (score 1):

The more acceptable way to achieve this is to derive from [`std::basic_filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) and use it to wrap the original stream buffer.  You would then perform the decryption (and encryption if you want to support writing) of the stream data prior to handing it off to the `fstream`.

You can access and replace the stream buffer with your own one by calling [`std::fstream::rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf). In your case you could open the file, pass the filebuf into your custom one and then replace the stream buffer.

There are a lot of functions in this class, but you should only need to handle a few.  You probably have some extra rules about valid operations, such as random seeks invalidating your decryption state machine, etc...

Comment: I hoped it would be simpler that that... C++ seems to have an affinity for making things as complicated as possible.

Comment: It's actually trying to make things as flexible as possible.  Overriding an interface like `fstream` is absolutely misunderstanding what `fstream` does.

Comment: Haha I didn't mean to defend C++ so strongly.  I know what you're saying.  Anyway, I looked up something that might make you feel a bit better about it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11836485/1553090